# RobotFramework : Getting testcase results while execution is in progress

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework

We are using Robot framework and RIDE tool for test case execution. we have 100+ testcases and test execution takes more than 6 hours to complete.

RF result and log html is great for viewing results. But these 2 files are viewable only after completion of test case execution.

*Is there any plugin / tool or mechanism to view the testcase result status during execution.*  in RIDE tool -"Run" tab - only shows pass:<> fail:<> and not very user useful.

Need real time testcase status report instead of waiting for completion

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [listener interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-listener-interface). With it, you can have robot framework call a python function each time a keyword, testcase or suite starts and finishes. For the case where they finish, the data that is passed in will include the pass or fail status.

Answer (score 1):

Using the listener interface (as Bryan Oakley suggested) is surely the most flexible way to intercept test progession status. If you are looking for tools, Jenkins ([with Robot Framework plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Robot+Framework+Plugin)) gives you the opportunity to follow a test run in real time at test case granularity. Just start a job and switch to (Jenkins) console to see the output dropping in.